# Contents of flexbox spilling over despite overflow-auto

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

I am having an issue with a site I'm building, and its an issue of nested flex boxes where the inner content is scrollable. My issue is that the scrollable content is causing something to extend beyond the edge of the desired borders, and then become "cut off" as they extend beyond the screen.

This represents the issue pretty closely:

```css
.main-site-container{
  min-height: 768px;
  min-width: 1350px;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  border-style: groove;
  color: orange;
  
}

.main-app-container {
  min-height: 768px;
  min-width: 1350px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  display: flex;
  color: turquoise;
  border-style: ridge;
}

.main-app{
  min-height: 683px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 1125px;
  width: 100%;
  border-style: dotted;
  color: pink;
}

.main-app-content {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-style: solid;
  color: green;
}

.app-page {
  color: #565A5E;
  overflow: auto;
  border-style: dashed;
  height: 100%;
}

.heading-w-card-container {
  align-items: flex-start;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 0;
  border-style: inset;
  color: black;
}

.heading {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-style: normal;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  line-height: 1.75rem;
  color: cadetblue;
}

.card-list{
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: min-content max-content auto;
  gap: 20px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 0;
  background: darksalmon;
  color: red;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  width: fit-content;
  height: auto;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 60px;
  background: blue;
  border-style: groove;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-site-container">
    Main site - static
    <div class="main-app-container">
    Main App Container, sidebar, etc. overall static
        <div class="main-app">
        Main app - static
            <div class="main-app-content">
            Main app content - static
              <div class="app-page">
        static itself, but content is dynamic - switches out based on page
                <div class="heading-w-card-container">
                  <div class="heading">My Heading</div>
                  <div class="card-list">
                    <div class="card">
                      <h1>This is a card</h1>
                      Blah blah blah
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                      <h1>This is a card</h1>
                      Blah blah blah
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                      <h1>This is a card</h1>
                      Blah blah blah
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                      <h1>This is a card</h1>
                      Blah blah blah
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                      <h1>This is a card</h1>
                      Blah blah blah
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                      <h1>This is a card</h1>
                      Blah blah blah
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                      <h1>This is a card</h1>
                      Blah blah blah
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                      <h1>This is a card</h1>
                      Blah blah blah
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                      <h1>This is a card</h1>
                      Blah blah blah
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                      <h1>This is a card</h1>
                      Blah blah blah
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                      <h1>This is a card</h1>
                      Blah blah blah
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pzqj3deu/1/)

Due to the app's layout - I can't really touch anything higher than `app-page`. Firefox's dev tools is telling me that `heading` and `card` are whats causing the overflow. I've tried looking at other similar questions, and they seem to suggest setting `min-height:0` or adding `overflow:hidden` in some areas. I've tried various combinations on that, but can't seem to get any changes to take.

The difference in this code snippet and my app is that the first element that appears to go off the page is `heading-w-card-container` on my app, as opposed to all of the elements not having a visible bottom border here.

What I would like to see is everything within the `card-list` to be contained to the boundaries of the screen, with a scroll that does actually allow you to see the bottom of the last card. My guess too is I should be able to see all bottom borders in the window. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**overflow: hidden** is hiding your content too that is why it seems like it was cut off. But instead of using that if you use **overflow: auto** and add this to your CSS. This line of code will help you hide only the scroll bar.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```